# Vectorized approach for calculating numerator for generalized binomial theorem?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray, binomial-theorem

I am trying to program the generalized binomial theorem, where n can be any rational number, using a vectorized approach. Formula attached as image below.

The numerator for each term is n, n×(n-1) , n×(n-1)×(n-2) and so on. I have assigned 0.5 to n to and am trying to generate 5 terms.

So far, I have an array of the products of the numerator:
[ 0.5 -0.5 -1.5 -2.5 -3.5]
using

```
def num_products(number_of_terms):
    r = np.arange(1,number_of_terms+1)
    num_prod = np.array(n-r+1)
    return num_prod
```

But want to create an array of the numerators for each terms, like this (w each item in array shown separated by commas):

[ 0.5, 0.5×-0.5, 0.5×-0.5×-1.5, 0.5×-0.5×-1.5×-2.5, 0.5×-0.5×-1.5×-2.5×-3.5]

Does anyone know how to do this using arrays (vectorized approach)? I am trying to make it very quick to compute the terms so I can have a larger number of terms and increase accuracy of the result.

[Formula for generalized binomial theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZaM7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each term `x*(x-1)*(x-2)*...*(x - n + 1)` is known as a [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).  The wikipedia article also describes the *rising factorial* `x*(x+1)*...*(x + n - 1)`.  Some computational libraries include implementations of these.  For example, [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/) has [`mpmath.ff`](http://mpmath.org/doc/0.19/functions/gamma.html#ff) and [`mpmath.rf`](http://mpmath.org/doc/0.19/functions/gamma.html#rf).

SciPy implements the rising factorial as [`scipy.special.poch`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.poch.html).  The falling factorial can be implemented in terms of the rising factorial, as in

```
from scipy.special import poch


def ff(x, m):
    return poch(x - m + 1, m)
```

Because `poch` is implemented as a NumPy "ufunc", it handles broadcasting, and therefore so does `ff`.  This means you can pass in an array of values for `m` to compute all the corresponding falling factorials with one call.

For example, to get the first six numerator terms (including the initial term 1) of the generalized binomial with n = 0.5, call `ff(0.5, np.arange(6))`:

```
In [38]: ff(0.5, np.arange(6))
Out[38]: array([ 1.     ,  0.5    , -0.25   ,  0.375  , -0.9375 ,  3.28125])
```

That is the same as `[1, 0.5, 0.5×-0.5, 0.5×-0.5×-1.5, 0.5×-0.5×-1.5×-2.5, 0.5×-0.5×-1.5×-2.5×-3.5]`:

```
In [40]: [1, 0.5, 0.5*-0.5, 0.5*-0.5*-1.5, 0.5*-0.5*-1.5*-2.5, 0.5*-0.5*-1.5*-2.5*-3.5]
Out[40]: [1, 0.5, -0.25, 0.375, -0.9375, 3.28125]
```

So if you don't mind the dependence on SciPy, you can use `ff` defined above to do what you want.